# How does base64_encode in PHP return LF (UNIX) values?

Tags: php

I use Ubuntu server and try to base64_encode a string value but default result return CRLF (Windows), how do return value be LF (UNIX)

```
<?php
$str = 'this is
       the string
       value in
       my image';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

LF(UNIX) output:

> dGhpcyBpcwp0aGUgc3RyaW5nCnZhbHVlIGluCm15IGltYWdl

CRLF(Windows) output:

> dGhpcyBpcw0KdGhlIHN0cmluZw0KdmFsdWUgaW4NCm15IGltYWdl

This is image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7BSy.png)

Comment: Neither does the value in your example contain any newlines, nor does the output base64-encoding it will create.

Comment: The "destination newline separator" option the tool you are using there offers, only becomes relevant when you use the "Split lines into 76 character wide chunks (useful for MIME)" option. And that splitting is not part of the job of `base64_encode` to begin with. If you want this on top of the base64 encoding, then use `chunk_split`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all new line breaker to the UNIX line break:

```
$replace = str_replace(["\r\n","\r"],"\n", "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHkjCCBXqgAwIBAgIRASAKILmJPzFKosrVlk8kxJMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQENBQAw
gYkxMjAwBgNVBAMMKVRFU1pUIE5UQUstQ0EgQ2xpZW50IEF1dGggU2lnbmluZyBD
QSAyMDIzMR0wGwYDVQQLDBRURVNaVCBEQVRSQUstQ0EgMjAyMzEUMBIGA1UECgwL");

base64_encode($replace);
```

This worked for me, hope I could help you too!